# Empty Subset of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need an example of a empty subset V of a vector space over field F that satisfies conditions:

if x,y∈V, then (x+y)∈V

and

if x∈V and λ∈F, then λ⋅x∈V

Of course empty set satisfies those conditions, but is it possible to write set of conditions for empty set, such that they satisfy those conditions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking for examples of subsets satisfying these conditions other than the empty set? Or do you want conditions equivalent to these? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I just need some description of a empty set in a form of V={v , condition a, condition b, condition c...}, so that we can see that set is closed under scalar multiplication and addition... 
(of course those conditions cant be mutually met and set is empty, but i cant explicitely write any conditions that give me empty set and satisfy conditions from question)

Comment: You mean something like $V=\{v\in F^n | v \neq v \}$ or $V=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<0 \}$?

Comment: Yes. But that example doesnt satisfy second condition  for λ=0 (where 0 is additive identity of F).

Comment: The empty set is scalar and translation invariant

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Why are you asking this exactly? It's a bit of strange question...

Comment: What is wrong with describing the empty set as $\emptyset$? All you need to know about $\emptyset$ is that $x\notin \emptyset$, no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: @Arnaud D. Because my professor didnt give us third condition (V is nonempty) when he defined subspaces. After i pointed out that that means empty set is a subspace of every space, he said that empty set probably cant be "defined" so that it meets first 2 conditions other then saying V=∅.

@ Hagen von Eitzen Nothing is wrong with ∅. I am just curious to see, can it be done in  a "descriptive" way.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you said:

> "Yes. But that example [of "some empty set"] doesnt satisfy second condition for λ=0"

*The* empty set is unique (it does not matter how you describe it) and it *does* satisfy that second condition even for $\lambda = 0$, since $\forall x \in \varnothing : 0\cdot x = 0 \in \varnothing$. Why? Because $\forall x\in \varnothing : \text{anything}$ is true; that is what makes the empty set empty: every members fulfills every condition since there are no members.

This is true even if $\text{anything}$ does not contain the variable $x$, because  $\forall x \in \varnothing : \text{anything}$ really means $\forall x : x\in \varnothing \Rightarrow \text{anything}$. Since $x\in \varnothing$ is false, such a statement is true always.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just looking for a way (if possible) to define empty set in such a way that I could "fool" someone that it is actually a subspace (if that someone checks just other two conditions for a subspace and doesnt check for nonemptiness).

Comment: @estamaster Well, you would need to use some complicated or unknown mathematics to come up with a condition that would temporarily fool someone. Many straightforward conditions, like the ones in Arnaud D. comment, are just obviously false. In any case, what condition "would fool people" is not a very mathematical question.